# Bash script using expect not recognizing output

Tags: regex, bash, expect

I'm trying to write an expect script that kill the running process and spawns the next command in the script.  I believe my issue is that the script isn't recognizing the correct output and as a result the script hangs where it should be killing the process.

Here is the exact outputs I'm trying to match

```
<Jan 26, 2015 8:38:05 AM PST> <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000365> <Server state changed to RUNNING.>
```

and here is what I have in the expect script

```
expect {
             -re "<\[^>\]*> <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000360> <Server started in RUNNING mode>.*$" { system kill -TSTP [exp_pid]; system kill -CONT [exp_pid]; send_user "\r\r" }
            -re "<\[^>\]*> <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000365> <Server state changed to RUNNING.>.*$" { system kill -TSTP [exp_pid]; system kill -CONT [exp_pid]; send_user "\r\r" }
            "<Notice> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000365> <Server state changed to RUNNING.>.*$" { system kill -TSTP [exp_pid]; system kill -CONT [exp_pid]; send_user "\r\r" }
    }'
```

I'm using regular expressions for the timestamp so I can match the entire line.

Any ideas on why it isn't matching the output?  Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the backslash before the `[` and `]`

```
<[^>]*>
```

ie,

```
-re "<[^>]*> <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000365> <Server state changed to RUNNING.>.*$"
```

In regex `[^...]` called negated character class. And `\[\]` matches the literal `[` and `]` characters.

Comment: Now I'm getting `invalid command name "^>"
    while executing
"^>"`

Comment: use `<.*>` or `<.*?>`